# Application Icon

Tags: android, icons

Can any one tell me how to change application icon  programmatically in android? Is it possible in android? requirement is, if we click on application icon it would have to change icon from drawable.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, all you can do to provide a similar experience is to use an icon-like widget.

Comment: Thnx..can you please tell me how to do that? cse m new in android. thnx a lot!!